# VueJS and Laravel get data from html <table> and do a bulk upload to laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to build a html  where I can add new rows then do a bulk upload to laravel and insert all items from the  to the database.

The table looks like this:

```
<div id="app">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Job</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.job"></td>
      <td><a @click="removeRow(row)">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
</div>
</div>

var app  = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [
      {name: "James Bond",job: "spy"},
      {name: "Goldfinger", job: "villain"}
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addRow: function(){
      this.rows.push({name:"",job:""});
    },
    removeRow: function(row){
      //console.log(row);
      this.rows.$remove(row);
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7nxhygLp/

Lets say that I have added 20 items in the  now I want to post that data to laravel and insert all 20 items at the same time.

So how do I get the data from my  using vueJS and how do I parse it in my controller to do a bulk upload?

Comment: They are in the `rows` field of your Vue instance. So either make a new method `sendRows` that accesses `this.rows` and uploads that using your XHR library of choice, or access `app.rows` from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7nxhygLp/282/

```
<div id="app">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Job</strong></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" v-model="row.job"></td>
      <td><a @click="removeRow(row)">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div>
  <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
  <button class="button btn-primary" @click="submitRows">Submit rows</button> <!-- Add this -->
</div>
</div>

var app  = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    rows: [
      {name: "James Bond",job: "spy"},
      {name: "Goldfinger", job: "villain"}
    ]
  },
  methods:{
    addRow: function(){
      this.rows.push({name:"",job:""});
    },
    removeRow: function(row){
      //console.log(row);
      this.rows.$remove(row);
    }, 
    submitRows: function() { // add the action
        axios.post('/api/link/here', rows)
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    }
  }
});
```

then, in your controller, iterate through the array and save to db:

```
foreach ($request['rows'] as $row) {
    [*addClassHere*]::create($row);
}
```

This is how I did it.